# OpenCV installation problems due to OpenJPEG, OpenBLAS, and VTK not found

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, raspberry-pi4

I've been following all the guides on how to install OpenJPEG, OpenBLAS, and VTK on webpages but still get these results when trying to perform the build using CMAKE in Ubuntu Raspberry Pi 4B. I'm totally new to using RPi, so forgive my lack of knowledge...

These are the error messages I've received when operating:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

on [here](https://core-electronics.com.au/guides/object-identify-raspberry-pi/)

Error Message:

`````
-- Found Jasper: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjasper.so (found version "1.900.1") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (found version "1.2.13") 
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Found Atlas: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf  
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf, library: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatlas.so)
-- LAPACK(Atlas): LAPACK_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatlas.so
-- LAPACK(Atlas): Support is enabled.
-- Found apache ant: /bin/ant (1.10.13)
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include  found components: AWT JVM 
-- Found Flake8: /usr/bin/flake8  
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- Carotene: NEON is not available, disabling carotene...
-- ADE: Download: v0.1.1f.zip
-- Try 1 failed
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVDownload.cmake:202 (message):
  ADE: Download failed: 28;"Timeout was reached"

  For details please refer to the download log file:

  /home/xjtlu/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeDownloadLog.txt

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/gapi/cmake/DownloadADE.cmake:5 (ocv_download)
  modules/gapi/cmake/init.cmake:19 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:312 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:375 (_add_modules_1)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)


**-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/xjtlu/opencv-4.4.0/build/python_loader
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   Package 'libavresample', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   Package 'gstreamer-base-1.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   Package 'gstreamer-app-1.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   Package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   Package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   Package 'libdc1394-2', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Module opencv_alphamat disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   NO
-- freetype2:   YES (ver 24.3.18)
-- harfbuzz:    YES (ver 6.0.0)
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found version "")
-- Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings. 
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
-- Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
-- Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
-- Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
-- Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Checking for module 'tesseract'
--   Package 'tesseract', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'int'
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse3.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.ssse3.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse4_2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.fp16.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin256.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin256.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin512.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/corner.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.sse4_1.cpp
-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/xjtlu/opencv-4.4.0/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/features2d/src/fast.avx2.cpp
-- xfeatures2d/boostdesc: Download: boostdesc_bgm.i
-- Try 1 failed

=======================================================================
  Couldn't connect to server from the Internet.
  Perhaps direct connections are not allowed in the current network.
  To use proxy please check/specify these environment variables:
  - http_proxy/https_proxy
  - and/or HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY
=======================================================================````
 

there are more messages but I figured it would be useless to post since it just kept trying to download.
`````

Comment: Just curious, by why are you building a version of OpenCV released in mid-2020? Latest is 4.9.0.

Comment: AFAIK, lack of OpenBLAS shouldn't be an issue, since it found Atlas+LAPACK. I don't see it complaining about OpenJPEG, and the source of that library is included in the source package anyway. Regarding VTK, do you actually intend to use that contrib module? If not, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The only thing I can really see it complaining about is the inability to download some build dependency. What is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

For those who face similar problems, because I currently am studying in China and haven't found how to connect my rpi with VPN, these are some methods I've used.

For some missing files that require VPN, I download it one by one from this [directory](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/tree/contrib_xfeatures2d_boostdesc_20161012?tab=readme-ov-file). From this link, try to download any files your RPi might be lacking.

I also find this [website](https://wiki.harvard.edu/confluence/display/DigitalImaging/Installing+OpenJPEG+on+Windows+10%2C+Linux%2C+and+MacOS) to help installing OpenJPEG. Wish me luck.